# If we apply force on sun, what happens to orbit of earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, centripetal-force

Earth is revolving around the sun. If we apply force on the sun and the sun moves away in any arbitrary direction, what happens to the orbit of earth? Will the earth also move along with sun with its orbit remaining as it is OR will the orbit change OR will the earth go away from the orbit?

**Note-** This question is different from my previous question "*What happens to the revolution of earth if we apply force on earth in any particular direction?*", in the sense that here the force is being applied on the sun.

Comment: Of course the orbit will change, but maybe if the sun is moving slow enough then an equilbrium can be achieved at every point. interesting question, I might work out the math and write a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is in fact completely equivalent to your other question, *What happens to the revolution of earth if we apply force on earth in any particular direction?"*:  Applying a force to the sun means it accelerates with some acceleration $a$. Transforming into an accelerated reference frame removes this acceleration, and in exchange gives rise to the opposite acceleration on the earth.  Thus, the situation is exactly equivalent to the situation where you apply the opposite acceleration to the earth.